# Como criar upload de arquivos sem usar "input file"?

Tags: php, mysql

Como faço para fazer um upload de arquivos sem incluir o `input file`,
ou seja, somente usando `textField` em HTML?

Consegui resolver pessoal segue abaixo a solução

```
<?php 
$numtotal=5;
$erro;

for($i=0;$i<$numtotal;$i++){
    $arquivo=$_POST['arquivo'][$i];
    $format=str_replace(".txt","",$arquivo);
    $tipoArq=substr($arquivo,-4);
    $arquivoinvert=strrev($arquivo);
    $arquivoinvert=strstr($arquivoinvert,"/",true);
    $arquivoinvert=strrev($arquivoinvert);

    if($tipoArq==".txt"){

            $arquivoinvert=str_replace(".txt","",$arquivoinvert);
            $formatadata=date("d-m-Y-h-i-s");
            $formatdata=str_replace("-","",$formatadata);       
            $caminho="/opt/lampp/htdocs/upload/uploads/".$arquivoinvert.$formatdata.$tipoArq;
            copy($arquivo,$caminho);
            include ("banco.php");

            echo $arquivo.'<br/>';

    }

    else{
        $erro="A extensão do arquivo não é valida";
        echo $erro;
    }
}



?>
```

Comment: Como assim? quer guardar somente a path e não o conteúdo?

Comment: Você quer sem `input`? Não seria `input` oculto? Veja este exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/u4W8G/

Comment: Existe um plugin em jQuery Dropzone que pode resolver seu problema: http://www.dropzonejs.com/

Comment: nao preciso mais @SilenoBrito, agradeço pela sugestão, eu fiz na unha usando o textfield ;)

Comment: Por favor, publique sua solução como Resposta. E confira a [ajuda de edição](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver pessoal segue abaixo a solução

```
<?php 
$numtotal=5;
$erro;

for($i=0;$i<$numtotal;$i++){
    $arquivo=$_POST['arquivo'][$i];
    $format=str_replace(".txt","",$arquivo);
    $tipoArq=substr($arquivo,-4);
    $arquivoinvert=strrev($arquivo);
    $arquivoinvert=strstr($arquivoinvert,"/",true);
    $arquivoinvert=strrev($arquivoinvert);

    if($tipoArq==".txt"){

            $arquivoinvert=str_replace(".txt","",$arquivoinvert);
            $formatadata=date("d-m-Y-h-i-s");
            $formatdata=str_replace("-","",$formatadata);        
            $caminho="/opt/lampp/htdocs/upload/uploads/".$arquivoinvert.$formatdata.$tipoArq;
            copy($arquivo,$caminho);
            include ("banco.php");

            echo $arquivo.'<br/>';

    }

    else{
        $erro="A extensão do arquivo não é valida";
        echo $erro;
    }
}



?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Se a sua ideia é passar a url de alguma imagem através do campo textField você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
<?php
    $url = "http://...."; //url da imagem que venha de um textField

    //PEGA INFORMAÇÕES DA IMAGEM
    $file_info = getimagesize($url);


    //VERIFICA EXTENSÃO DA IMAGEM
    if ($file_info['mime'] == "image/jpeg")
        $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($url);
    else if ($file_info['mime'] == "image/gif")
        $img = imagecreatefromgif($url);
    else if ($file_info['mime'] == "image/png")
        $img = imagecreatefrompng($url);

    $altura = $file_info[1];

    //PASSA AS MEDIDAS PARA A IMAGEM
    $x   = imagesx($img);
    $y   = imagesy($img);
    $largura = ($altura * $x)/$y;


    //CRIA A IMAGEM
    $nova = imagecreatetruecolor($largura, $altura);
    imagealphablending( $nova, false );
    imagesavealpha( $nova, true );
    imagecopyresampled($nova, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $largura, $altura, $x, $y);


    //NOME DA IMAGEM
    $imgName = end(explode("/", $url));

    //LOCAL PARA SALVAR
    $pasta = "."; // defina sua path
    $local = $pasta . $imgName;


    //SALVA NOVA IMAGEM
    if ($file_info['mime'] == "image/jpeg")
        imagejpeg($nova, $local, 100);
    else if ($file_info['mime'] == "image/png")
        imagepng($nova, $local, 9);

    //DESTROI ELEMENTOS
    imagedestroy($img);
    imagedestroy($nova);
?>
```

Comment: obrigado pelo post Guilherme mas me fale uma coisa preciso fazer com arquivos, e nao imagens...
tem algum exemplo???